# If $K$ is a countable field, then $K(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n)$ is a countable field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I'm trying to prove that if $K$ is a countable field and $L:K$ is finitely generated then L is countable.

Based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792756/finitely-generated-extension-of-a-countable-field) post, I know that it follows from the fact that if $K$ is a countable field, then $K(t_1, t_2, ..., t_n)$ is a countable field, but I am unsure of why this is true and how I would show this.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the data that specifies a rational function in $t_1, \ldots, t_n$?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein what do you mean by data?

Comment: He means what do you do when you write down an element of $K(\mathbf t)$.

Comment: K(t) is the set of rational expressions of polynomials in K or  ordered pairs of $(a,b)$ , $b\neq 0$ where $a,b \in K[t]$ modulo the equivalence relation $ad-bc = 0$, so then if $K[t]$ is countable, it would follow that $K(t)$ is, but then I'm further stuck on how to show $K[t]$ is countable.

Comment: @klamont15 Okay, that's a good start. Now how many linear polynomials are there? How many quadratic polynomials are there? How many cubic polynomials? Etc. Use the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Why would it be a union of countable sets instead of a Cartesian product? When I first was thinking about the problem I thought that to count them, you could represent each, for instance n-degree, polynomial as order n+1-tuples where the i-th entry corresponds to the coefficient in front of t^i or am I just thinking about this wrong

Comment: @klamont15 because every polynomial has finite degree - $\displaystyle \sum_i a_i t^i$ is not a polynomial unless all but finitely many $a_i$ are zero. So it's not arbitrary sequences of elements of $K$, just finite sequences.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein oh thank you so much